# Is the file named "stylesheet.css" necessary/mandatory?

Tags: css

Is the first file of CSS MUST/MANDATORY being named "stylesheet.css" or we can put it as "header.css" or "sidebar.css"?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that CSS files had naming conventions/restrictions? I'm not aware of any library or framework where they do. Just curious.

Comment: This is not a question of opinion, but a question of what is supported. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Oh I just thought about it when I'm starting a new project just now. As I made a file named index.html, I also made stylesheet.css but I want to rename it. But, I'm afraid that stylesheet.css name is mandatory and after I searched a lot, none came up. So, I asked here.

Edit: I'm new here so pardon me if I'm asking a bad question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS filename `stylesheet.css` is **not** mandatory; you can call it whatever you want.

**However**, you must correctly reference the filename in the `<head>` section of the HTML file. For example, if you had a stylesheet called `theme.css`, you would reference it as:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name the stylesheet anything as long as you link it in the head tag still.